# Stepwise creation of multidimensional arrays

Tags: java

My task is to create this array step by step.

```
int[][][] feld = new int[6][10][7];
```

Will my solution really do the same (I haven't figured out a way to find out)?:

```
int[][][] feld = new int[6][][];
for (int d1 = 0; d1 < feld.length; d1++) { 
     feld[d1] = new int [10];
     for (int d2 = 0; d2 < feld[d1].length; d2++) {
          feld[d1][d2] = new int[7];
     } 
}
```

Comment: Your solution cannot do the same, because it doesn't compile. The third line has a type error, since `feld[d1]` is of type `int[][]` but you are trying to assign an `int[]`.

Comment: @kaya3 oh, I didn't know I had to do it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will my solution really do the same (I haven't figured out a way to find out)?

Read the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), example [15.10.2-2. Multi-Dimensional Array Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#d5e25617):

> ```
> Age[][][][][] Aquarius = new Age[6][10][8][12][];
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> Age[][][][][] Aquarius = new Age[6][][][][];
> for (int d1 = 0; d1 < Aquarius.length; d1++) {
>     Aquarius[d1] = new Age[10][][][];
>     for (int d2 = 0; d2 < Aquarius[d1].length; d2++) {
>         Aquarius[d1][d2] = new Age[8][][];
>         for (int d3 = 0; d3 < Aquarius[d1][d2].length; d3++) {
>             Aquarius[d1][d2][d3] = new Age[12][];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

---

As pointed out in a [comment by kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791274/stepwise-creation-of-multidimensional-arrays/58791525#comment103864221_58791274): "The third line has a type error, since `feld[d1]` is of type `int[][]` but you are trying to assign an `int[]`".

```
int[][][] feld = new int[6][][];
for (int d1 = 0; d1 < feld.length; d1++) { 
    feld[d1] = new int[10][];   // <-- added extra [] here
    for (int d2 = 0; d2 < feld[d1].length; d2++) {
        feld[d1][d2] = new int[7];
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Aarooon I find it interesting that your code is using `d1` and `d2` as iterator variables, when it is customary to use `i` and `j`, and that the JLS uses `d1` and `d2`. Seems your code came from the JLS example.

Comment: it was a homework task of a college course to fill in blanks, so they probably took it from there :)